# How to backup LDAP without SSH account

Tags: ssh, ldap, virtual-machine, openldap

Hope someone might be able to help. We have a TurnKey VM running OpenLDAP however cannot SSH to the server and can only access LDAP. That's it.

https://www.turnkeylinux.org/openldap

Is there anyway to get the LDAP database without SSH access?
Otherwise, we have console access, however this is limited. When we SSH in to the server, it just stalls and nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: Get the vendor to fix the SSH login. Off topic.

Comment: LDIF would backup all the data entries but not the configuration information.